# Lubuntu live login error after editing image with Cubic

Tags: lubuntu

I am trying to build a live iso with a default user and some pre-installed packages. I have modified a vanilla Lubuntu 22.04 live image using Cubic. I have installed the packages I need and I have also added a default user as some packages add commands to the user `.bashrc`.

When booting the live image on VirtualBox I get the following syslog error:

[image: syslog error]

This is the content of `/etc/sddm.conf`:

[image: sddm.conf]

Is the user I created causing issues, even though in `sddm.conf` the default `lubuntu` user is used? The `sddm.conf` file is automatically generated. I tried looking for and editing the scripts that generate this file, but I always end up with the `lubuntu` user instead of the one I specified.

If I switch to another tty, login with the custom user and run `startx` I can continue with the installation, but I don't want users of this custom image to go through that.

Do you have any suggestions about how to solve this problem? Is there a better way to create a custom iso that also automatically creates a user with the necessary files in their home folder?

Comment: Are you trying to change the live user name from "lubuntu" to something else? Why do you need a default user preconfigured? (In other words, why can't the user installing the ISO simply chose their own user name and password during installation)?

Comment: A piece of software I wanted to pre-install writes to the `.bashrc` file, so I wanted the image to already have a user with the modified `.bashrc`. In the end I removed the custom user and users of the iso will have to install that software manually if needed.

Comment: Do you know about the `skel` folder, and have you tried that?

Comment: I was not aware of that. Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In Cubic, navigate to the `/etc/skel` directory.

   This directory contains files that will be copied into the home folder of each new user that is created.

   ```
   cd /etc/skel
   ```

   [image: Cubic Terminal page before copying the file]
2. Then drag your customized `.bash` file onto the Cubic window to copy it into the current directory.

   [image: Cubic Copy File page]
3. Click the <kbd>Copy</kbd> button, and the file will be copied there.

   [image: Cubic Terminal page after copying the file]
4. Once you generate your customized ISO, the `.bash` file will appear in each new user's home directory. This is because the `skel` directory acts as a "skeleton" for users' home directories. The `adduser` command (used by the installer, or whenever you create a new user using the GUI) copies the contents of this directory into the new user's home directory and sets the permissions accordingly.